# How to using replace with variable?

Tags: php, preg-replace

$aaa = preg_replace('/<%var.*\$(fullname).*%>/is', $_SESSION["\1"], $aaa);

Comment: What are you asking? You need to supply a little more detail.

Comment: any programer and know its easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead:

```
$line = preg_replace_callback(
    '/<%var.\$(fullname).%>/is',
    create_function(
        '$matches',
        'return $_SESSION[$matches[1]];'
    ),
    $line
);
```

Though I would be wary of where you're getting the input string from: I would be wary if it's coming from users (it looks like it might be coming from some kind of configuration or template file, though, which is probably OK).